# compare multiple columns in two files, replace value in file 2 with value from file 1

Tags: python

I have two files: file *smaller_file* (0.24 million rows), *larger_file* (2.11 million rows)

*smaller_file* format

```
1       hsa-mir-183     Hepatocellular carcinoma        hsa-mir-374a    Hepatocellular carcinoma        0.97866 0       1
2       hsa-mir-374a    Hepatocellular carcinoma        hsa-mir-182     Hepatocellular carcinoma        0.97816 0       1
... (so on)
```

*larger_file* format

```
1       hsa-mir-181c    Thyroid carcinoma, papillary    hsa-mir-221     Thyroid carcinoma, papillary    16365291        16365291        -1.00000        1
2       hsa-mir-220a    Thyroid carcinoma, papillary    hsa-mir-221     Thyroid carcinoma, papillary    16365291        16365291        -1.00000        1
... (so on)
```

*smaller_file* with `8` columns and *larger_file* with `9` columns. I am comparing rows `2` to `5` in both files and if they are the same, I need to replace column `8` value in *larger_file* with column `6` value in *smaller_file*. This is what I've so far:

```
clines = set("\t".join(cline.split('\t')[1:5]) for cline in open(smaller_file))

print "set created!"
with open(larger_file) as a:
    with open("scores.txt", "w") as result:
        for line in a:
            line = line.split('\t')
            look_for = "\t".join(line[1:5])
            if look_for in clines:
                # below line is incomplete as I don't have the 6th column value from smaller_file
                result.write("\t".join(line[1:7]) + "\t" + line[len(line)-1].split("\n")[0] + "\n")
```

I am using the `set` operation to avoid *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* with two for loops. However, I can't capture the `6th` column from *smaller_file* using `set` operation. doing so would make the comparison in `9th` line hard since indexing isn't supported for `set` operation. I can use another for loop after `9th` line to look up `6th` column but it increases the complexity and defeats the purpose of `set` operation.

Any help to fix this is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain the "I am comparing rows 2 to 5 in both files and if they are the same" part? Maybe give an example.

Comment: I'm looking for the same corresponding column values in two files: same col 2 value in file 1 and 2, same col 3 value in file 1 and 2. The same for cols 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a dictionary instead of a set to read in the values from 'smaller_file'.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Your code would then look like this:

```
clines_dict = {} #open an empty dictionary

with open(smaller_file) as b:
    for line in b:
        clines_dict["\t".join(line.split('\t')[1:5])] = [line.split('\t')[5]]

# clines_dict[key] = [value]

print "dictionary created!"

with open(larger_file) as a:
    with open("scores.txt", "w") as result:
        for line in a:
            line = line.split('\t')
            look_for = "\t".join(line[1:5])
            if look_for in clines_dict: #check if look_for is a key in your dictionary
                result.write("\t".join(line[1:7]) + "\t" + clines_dict[look_for][0] + "\n")
```

In the last step of the loop, you check if "look_for" is a key in your dictionary, if yes, you retrieve the value (your column 6) belonging to that key. Another good way to do such things is using sql.